# Using perfunctory correctly

Tags: spelling-pronunciations

Perfunctory is defined as doing something in a hasty, cursory manner. Would it be correct to use this word as *perfunctorily* as well? If not, what would be the correct usage? 
For example, if you were to tell someone not to do something so perfunctorially.

My gut instinct says yes but I'm being flagged by word processors and Google search for an incorrect spelling.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=perfunctorily

Answer (score 0):

The Oxford Living Dictionaries [perfunctorily](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/perfunctorily) accept the word.
The word is a bit awkward to pronounce, but it is OK to use.

Other words  could work as substitutes, [thoughtlessly](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thoughtlessly), for example.
**Perfunctorily**  is not a word  I would expect to be used very often, I would sooner expect to be asked not to perform something so [mechcanically.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mechanically)

Comment: +1, it's even awkward to visually parse. Adjusting the grammar to fit the word "perfunctory" as-is would probably be a reasonable middle-ground.